# Unlock session is taking a long time

Tags: release-juno

On a fresh install of juno on my laptop, when I try to unlock my session it takes between 30s and 2m to respond.
I fill my password, sometimes I have to wait facing a black screen. Sometimes it shows the open windows, but none of the buttons and other UI elements are clickable, the time is wrong. 
I was having this problem with the beta release, but now with the stable on a claen installation  the problem persists.

Some of my specs:
(I'm using intel video card only)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug where this happens only after lock/suspend. Is this your case, or it behaves like this right after boot?